# Outlook web AddIn. Use ExecutionFunction to open web page in separate window instead of task pane. In the MessageReadCommandSurface

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Manifest file change

```
                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                      <FunctionName>loadPage</FunctionName>
                    </Action>

 <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
```

FunctionFile.js

```
function loadPage(event) {
    alert("Venkat Show Add-In");
    event.completed();
    event = null;
}
```

This loadPage function is not executed.

Script in loadPage is not executed. Is there any confiuguration issue here. `

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `FunctionFile` in the manifest to associate your function name (`loadPage`) with the web page where it is defined, for example, if you try to scaffold a new add-in solution using the yeoman generator (any office add-in with a task pane) you may find something like that:

```
<Host xsi:type="MailHost">
   <DesktopFormFactor>
      <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
```

Where the `<FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>` elements points to the string which points to the web page. In my case that looks like that:

```
<bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. My function file element is correctly configured only  <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

Comment: What do you expect to be opened in Outlook? A popup window instead of a task pane?

Comment: Exactly, need to open popup window instead of task pane.

Comment: Use the [Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) for such tasks.